# Gollum Wiki for Windows?

Tags: asp.net, azure, github, wiki, gollum-wiki

https://github.com/gollum/gollum -  ‘Gollum is a simple wiki system built on top of Git.’

Gollum is great but it’s written in Ruby (I'm not insinuating that there is anything wrong with that).

I want to use it as part of an existing ASP.NET website (Or as a standalone website) on Azure.

Has anybody already created an ASP.NET version? Or is there any other Wiki that is anywhere near as simple as Gollum?

Answer (score 1):

Just install `jruby`:

```
choco install jruby -y
```

Install gollum:

```
gem install gollum
```

Run it

```
gollum /D:/Wiki
```

Another option would be to [use it with WSL](https://www.wolffhaven45.com/2018/04/01/installing-gollum-on-windows-10/)
[How to use gollum on Windows? Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141896/how-to-use-gollum-on-windows-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run it as an azure VM.  Since grit doesn't not work on windows.

Azure has pre-built linux vm's that you can deploy then install your required software.

(Or make a windows friendly version of grit)