# How to use gollum on Windows? Is it possible?

Tags: ruby, windows

I want to use the wiki on [GitHub](https://github.com/gollum/gollum), and also use without Internet.
So I focus on gollum -- A git-based Wiki,but it is not possible on Windows.
But in the `README.md` on GitHub, they say in the Windows JRuby (1.9.3+ compatible) is needed, and gollum is almost supported.

I want to ask for a guide about how to use gollum on Windows, but i don't find further.

Answer (score 3):

So according to [a comment](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/23#issuecomment-653012205) (from 2020) in [the ticket linked](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/23) in the other answer, it is possible to run Gollum using JRuby.

I just tried that (February 2021) with JRuby 9.2.14.0 and it worked for me.

Brief instructions (from said comment):

> Just use the JRuby for Windows installer and `gem install gollum`.

Comment: @miile7 Ah, so even the official Ruby (not just JRuby) works. Great to know.

Comment: sorry, I have to revert my comment. I have never used ruby before. I just discovered that the install did not work properly. I couldn't run `gollum` and I thought it was caused by some other issues. But you are right, it seems like it does not work with plain ruby :(

Comment: @miile7 Fair enough, but it still means you could give JRuby a try. Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There is a discussion of Gollom's Windows support here. There are a few nasty hacks to get some of it working, but if you value your time choose another wiki.

https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/23

There have been several other Gollum based projects like [Realms Wiki](http://realms.io/) but they continued to have problems with Windows. There are lots of enthusiastic discussions between people who want to get them working under Windows but there appears to be too many issues relating to Posix/Windows incompatibilities that it didn't seem worth the time or effort to make it work.

The general advice moved towards installing Vagrant, VirtualBox, [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or another virtual machine and run it under a Unix operating system instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have installed ubuntu to use the gollum, it's really easy.So I get your suggestion to intall a virtual machine to run gollum on windows.

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer, or at least up vote it!

Comment: Sorry,I am a fresh here."Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 2):

**@20211225 - gollum on Windows 10**

1. Install cmake (https://cmake.org/download/)
   *I've used cmake-3.22.1-windows-x86_64.msi*
2. Install ruby (https://rubyinstaller.org/)
   *I've used Ruby+Devkit 3.0.3-1 (x64)*
3. gem install gollum
   Installation really took a while, then be patient.

Everything worked ok.

I've had just problems to make gollum to access the home.md
page of my wiki, then I solved it using this url
**http://localhost:4567/home.md**